# Oracle SQL Performance Tuning

Tags: sql, oracle, performance

I am currently working on the performance tuning of Oracle Quote search function. The sql as below

```
SELECT * FROM ASO_PAYMENTS_V WHERE quote_header_id = 718396 AND quote_line_id IS NULL;
```

ASO_PAYMENTS_V is a oracle canned view. The cost of the explain plan is low, but the execution time of the query is high. The explain plan is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a01paehim66av4e/explain_plan.txt?dl=0)

This query takes approximately 4 seconds to be executed. In the trace file I noticed that the quote search function will trigger this view for twice. In the other words, 8 out of 11 seconds of the processing time occupied by this view.

My questions

1. Any reason why the cost is low but the processing time is high?
2. Any performance tuning actions suggested?

Explain plain:

```
Plan hash value: 3846324179

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                               | Name                         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                                        |                              |     1 |   423 |    50   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                    | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES            |     1 |    59 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                                      | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES_U1         |     1 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                     |                              |     1 |   423 |    50   (6)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |   NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                    |                              |     1 |   125 |    10   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                   |                              |     1 |   114 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                 | ASO_PAYMENTS                 |     1 |    63 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                                   | ASO_PAYMENTS_N1              |     4 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  8 |     INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                   | FND_LOOKUP_VALUES_U2         |     1 |    51 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   9 |    VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                                | RA_TERMS_VL                  |     1 |    11 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  10 |     NESTED LOOPS                                        |                              |     1 |    44 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  11 |      NESTED LOOPS                                       |                              |     1 |    44 |     5   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  12 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                |                              |     1 |    24 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  13 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED              | RA_TERMS_B                   |     1 |     7 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 14 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN                                | RA_TERMS_B_U1                |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 15 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                | AR_CONS_BILL_CYCLES_TL_U1    |     1 |    17 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 16 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN                                  | RA_TERMS_TL_U1               |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  17 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                        | RA_TERMS_TL                  |     1 |    20 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  18 |   VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                                 | IBY_TRXN_EXTENSIONS_V        |     1 |   298 |    40   (8)| 00:00:01 |
|  19 |    NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                   |                              |     1 |   313 |    36   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  20 |     NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                  |                              |     1 |   297 |    33  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|  21 |      NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                 |                              |     1 |   291 |    32  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|  22 |       NESTED LOOPS OUTER                                |                              |     1 |   253 |    30  (10)| 00:00:01 |
|  23 |        NESTED LOOPS OUTER                               |                              |     1 |   240 |    29  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|  24 |         NESTED LOOPS OUTER                              |                              |     1 |   238 |    28  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|  25 |          NESTED LOOPS                                   |                              |     1 |   174 |    27  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|  26 |           NESTED LOOPS OUTER                            |                              |     1 |   169 |    26  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|  27 |            NESTED LOOPS OUTER                           |                              |     1 |   154 |    19  (11)| 00:00:01 |
|  28 |             NESTED LOOPS OUTER                          |                              |     1 |   139 |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  29 |              NESTED LOOPS OUTER                         |                              |     1 |   126 |    12   (9)| 00:00:01 |
|  30 |               NESTED LOOPS                              |                              |     1 |   113 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  31 |                NESTED LOOPS                             |                              |     1 |    89 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  32 |                 NESTED LOOPS OUTER                      |                              |     1 |    68 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  33 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_EXTENSIONS     |     1 |    46 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 34 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_EXTENSIONS_U1  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  35 |                  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID            | IBY_PMT_INSTR_USES_ALL       |     1 |    22 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 36 |                   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | IBY_PMT_INSTR_USES_ALL_U1    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 37 |                 INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                       | IBY_FNDCPT_PMT_CHNNLS_B_U1   |     1 |    21 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 38 |                INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | IBY_FNDCPT_PMT_CHNNLS_TL_U1  |     1 |    24 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 39 |               VIEW                                      |                              |     1 |    13 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|* 40 |                FILTER                                   |                              |       |       |            |          |
|  41 |                 SORT GROUP BY                           |                              |     1 |    76 |     9  (12)| 00:00:01 |
|* 42 |                  FILTER                                 |                              |       |       |            |          |
|  43 |                   NESTED LOOPS                          |                              |     1 |    76 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  44 |                    NESTED LOOPS                         |                              |     3 |    76 |     8   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  45 |                     NESTED LOOPS                        |                              |     1 |    34 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  46 |                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS     |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 47 |                       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS_N1  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  48 |                      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS     |     1 |    23 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 49 |                       INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS_N1  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 50 |                     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | IBY_TRXN_SUMM_TRANS_ID_N1    |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 51 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID          | IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL       |     1 |    42 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  52 |                   SORT AGGREGATE                        |                              |     1 |    30 |            |          |
|* 53 |                    TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED  | IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL       |     1 |    30 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 54 |                     INDEX RANGE SCAN                    | IBY_TRXN_SUMM_TRANS_ID_N1    |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 55 |              INDEX RANGE SCAN                           | IBY_DEBIT_AUTHORIZATIONS_N2  |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 56 |             VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                       |                              |     1 |    15 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  57 |              WINDOW SORT                                |                              |     1 |    47 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  58 |               NESTED LOOPS                              |                              |     1 |    47 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  59 |                NESTED LOOPS                             |                              |     3 |    47 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  60 |                 TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED     | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS     |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 61 |                  INDEX RANGE SCAN                       | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS_N1  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 62 |                 INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | IBY_TRXN_SUMM_TRANS_ID_N1    |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 63 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID              | IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL       |     1 |    36 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 64 |            VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                        |                              |     1 |    15 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  65 |             WINDOW SORT                                 |                              |     1 |    32 |     7  (15)| 00:00:01 |
|  66 |              NESTED LOOPS                               |                              |     1 |    32 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  67 |               NESTED LOOPS                              |                              |     3 |    32 |     6   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  68 |                TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED      | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS     |     1 |    11 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 69 |                 INDEX RANGE SCAN                        | IBY_FNDCPT_TX_OPERATIONS_N1  |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 70 |                INDEX RANGE SCAN                         | IBY_TRXN_SUMM_TRANS_ID_N1    |     3 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 71 |               TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID               | IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL       |     1 |    21 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 72 |           INDEX RANGE SCAN                              | FND_APPLICATION_U1           |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  73 |          TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                    | IBY_CREDITCARD               |     1 |    64 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 74 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | IBY_CREDITCARD_INSTRID_U1    |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  75 |         VIEW PUSHED PREDICATE                           | IBY_CREDITCARD_ISSUERS_V     |     1 |     2 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  76 |          NESTED LOOPS                                   |                              |     1 |    37 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 77 |           TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                   | IBY_CREDITCARD_ISSUERS_B     |     1 |    18 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 78 |            INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                            | IBY_CREDITCARD_ISSUERS_B_U1  |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 79 |           INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                             | IBY_CREDITCARD_ISSUERS_TL_U1 |     1 |    19 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  80 |        TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                      | IBY_EXT_BANK_ACCOUNTS        |     1 |    13 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 81 |         INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                               | IBY_EXT_BANK_ACCOUNTS_U1     |     1 |       |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  82 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID                       | HZ_PARTIES                   |     1 |    38 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 83 |        INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                | HZ_PARTIES_U1                |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 84 |      INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                                  | HZ_PARTIES_U1                |     1 |     6 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 85 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED                 | HZ_ORGANIZATION_PROFILES     |     1 |    16 |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 86 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                                   | HZ_ORGANIZATION_PROFILES_N1  |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - access("LOOKUP_TYPE"='IBY_CARD_EXPIRATION_STATUS' AND "VIEW_APPLICATION_ID"=0 AND 
              "LOOKUP_CODE"=DECODE(DECODE(:B1,NULL,:B2,DECODE(SIGN(:B3-SYSDATE@!),(-1),'Y','N')),'Y','EXPIRED','N','UNEXPIRED') AND 
              "LANGUAGE"=USERENV('LANG') AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='SET1')
       filter("LANGUAGE"=USERENV('LANG') AND "SECURITY_GROUP_ID"="FND_GLOBAL"."LOOKUP_SECURITY_GROUP"("LOOKUP_TYPE","VIEW_APPLIC
              ATION_ID") AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='SET1')
   6 - filter("PAYMENT"."QUOTE_LINE_ID" IS NULL)
   7 - access("PAYMENT"."QUOTE_HEADER_ID"=718396)
   8 - access("LOOKUP_TYPE"(+)='ASO_PAYMENT_TYPE' AND "VIEW_APPLICATION_ID"(+)=697 AND 
              "PAYMENT"."PAYMENT_TYPE_CODE"="MEANING"(+) AND "SECURITY_GROUP_ID"(+)=0 AND "LANGUAGE"(+)=USERENV('LANG') AND 
              "ZD_EDITION_NAME"(+)='SET1')
  14 - access("B"."TERM_ID"="PAYMENT"."PAYMENT_TERM_ID")
  15 - access("B"."BILLING_CYCLE_ID"="BILLING_CYCLE_ID"(+) AND "LANGUAGE"(+)=USERENV('LANG') AND 
              "ZD_EDITION_NAME"(+)='ORA$BASE')
  16 - access("T"."TERM_ID"="PAYMENT"."PAYMENT_TERM_ID" AND "T"."LANGUAGE"=USERENV('LANG'))
       filter("B"."TERM_ID"="T"."TERM_ID")
  34 - access("EXTN"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="PAYMENT"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
  36 - access("EXTN"."INSTR_ASSIGNMENT_ID"="U"."INSTRUMENT_PAYMENT_USE_ID"(+))
  37 - access("EXTN"."PAYMENT_CHANNEL_CODE"="PAYMENT_CHANNEL_CODE" AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='ORA$BASE')
  38 - access("LANGUAGE"=USERENV('LANG') AND "PAYMENT_CHANNEL_CODE"="PAYMENT_CHANNEL_CODE" AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='ORA$BASE')
  39 - filter("EXTN"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="AUTHTXN"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"(+))
  40 - filter("OP"."TRANSACTIONID"=MIN("TRANSACTIONID"))
  42 - filter("TRXNTYPEID"=2 OR "TRXNTYPEID"=3 OR "TRXNTYPEID"=20 AND "SUMM"."TRXNMID"= (SELECT MAX("TRXNMID") FROM 
              "IBY"."IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL" "IBY_TRXN_SUMMARIES_ALL" WHERE "TRANSACTIONID"=:B1 AND "REQTYPE"='ORAPMTREQ' AND "TRXNTYPEID"=20 
              AND ("STATUS"=0 OR "STATUS"=100 OR "STATUS"=111)))
  47 - access("TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="PAYMENT"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
  49 - access("OP"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="PAYMENT"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
       filter("TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="OP"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
  50 - access("SUMM"."TRANSACTIONID"="OP"."TRANSACTIONID")
  51 - filter("REQTYPE"='ORAPMTREQ' AND ("STATUS"=0 OR "STATUS"=100 OR "STATUS"=111))
  53 - filter("REQTYPE"='ORAPMTREQ' AND "TRXNTYPEID"=20 AND ("STATUS"=0 OR "STATUS"=100 OR "STATUS"=111))
  54 - access("TRANSACTIONID"=:B1)
  55 - access("EXTN"."DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION_ID"="AUTH"."DEBIT_AUTHORIZATION_ID"(+))
  56 - filter("SETTLETXN"."RANK"(+)=1)
  61 - access("OP"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="EXTN"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
  62 - access("SUMM"."TRANSACTIONID"="OP"."TRANSACTIONID")
  63 - filter(("REQTYPE"='ORAPMTCAPTURE' AND ("INSTRTYPE"='CREDITCARD' OR "INSTRTYPE"='PURCHASECARD') OR 
              "INSTRTYPE"='PINLESSDEBITCARD' AND "REQTYPE"='ORAPMTREQ' OR "TRXNTYPEID" IS NULL AND "INSTRTYPE"='BANKACCOUNT') AND ("STATUS"=0 
              OR "STATUS"=11 OR "STATUS"=100 OR "STATUS"=111))
  64 - filter("RETURNTXN"."RANK"(+)=1)
  69 - access("OP"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID"="EXTN"."TRXN_EXTENSION_ID")
  70 - access("SUMM"."TRANSACTIONID"="OP"."TRANSACTIONID")
  71 - filter("REQTYPE"='ORAPMTRETURN' AND ("STATUS"=0 OR "STATUS"=100 OR "STATUS"=111))
  72 - access("EXTN"."ORIGIN_APPLICATION_ID"="A"."APPLICATION_ID")
  74 - access("C"."INSTRID"(+)=DECODE("U"."INSTRUMENT_TYPE",'CREDITCARD',"U"."INSTRUMENT_ID",NULL))
  77 - filter("CARD_ISSUER_ACCEPTED_FLAG"='Y')
  78 - access("CARD_ISSUER_CODE"="C"."CARD_ISSUER_CODE" AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='ORA$BASE')
  79 - access("CARD_ISSUER_CODE"="C"."CARD_ISSUER_CODE" AND "LANGUAGE"=USERENV('LANG') AND "ZD_EDITION_NAME"='ORA$BASE')
  81 - access("B"."EXT_BANK_ACCOUNT_ID"(+)=DECODE("U"."INSTRUMENT_TYPE",'BANKACCOUNT',"U"."INSTRUMENT_ID",NULL))
  83 - access("C"."CARD_OWNER_ID"="HZP"."PARTY_ID"(+))
  84 - access("B"."BANK_ID"="BHZP"."PARTY_ID"(+))
  85 - filter(SYSDATE@!>=TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("BANKPROFILE"."EFFECTIVE_START_DATE"(+))) AND 
              SYSDATE@!<=NVL(TRUNC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("BANKPROFILE"."EFFECTIVE_END_DATE"(+))),SYSDATE@!+1))
  86 - access("BHZP"."PARTY_ID"="BANKPROFILE"."PARTY_ID"(+))
```

Comment: [The cost column in an execution plan is not a reliable way to judge the real costs of a SQL statements response time.](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_sql_execution_plan_cost_column.htm)

Comment: The optimiser thinks there will be very few rows to process and has therefore chosen a plan involving a lot of nested loops. Such plans tend not to scale up well for larger data volumes.My guess is there are more rows to process than it estimated.